# Import all data like users, post, comments etc to multisite

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress blog site and I am migrating it into WordPress multisite. We have more then 4000 users and approximate 3000 post and comments.

My requirement: Every existing user have their blog automatically. Like user jay have their blog example.com/jay or jay.example.com with their existing posts, pages and comments.

Example:
Suppose my blog website(not wp multisite) is http://www.myblogsite.com with 100 registered users.
raj, jay, rahul, tony etc etc.

User raj have 10 posts, 2 pages and 5 comments.

All post of user raj are showing on myblogsite.com/author/raj url.

Now, I want to migrate wp single site to wp multisite.

Then raj got thier blog automatically and url would be myblogsite.com/raj and all posts of raj showing there and pages as well.

My Question: Is there any plugin or script to export data from wp single site and import it into wp multisite so all users get their blog automatically with posts, pages and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the [WordPress Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) plugin, selecting "All content". Just import from the single blog, and export in the multisite subsite.